# Beginner Magento 2 Development without SSH

Tags: magento2, ssh

I've been developing and become quite familiar with another framework, but I'd like to start learning and seriously taking on Magento 2.

My host is a shared linux environment that DOES NOT provide SSH capability. They do have a commercial option that does provide SSH.

However, I'm not wiling to fork out for this just yet, until I feel I'm ready or familiar enough with Magento 2.

I was able to install Magento 2 through cPanel and Softaculous, and got it running just fine. But on further experimentation, I realized SSH is essential - until I stumbled upon some helpful posts that pointed out PHP's system() command.

My question is really, as a beginner, will system() be enough for the time-being? I'm able to change store modes, enable/disable maintenance, static deployment and several others.

Thanks and apologies, compared to my previous framework, Magento 2 is quite overwhelming and the amount of resources available online are so vast. My previous php cart was just everything in one single forum.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand your pain being the beginner in Magento2. Yes, it is fact that you need to rely on SSH connection to change store modes, enable/disable maintenance, static deployment and several other things.

We need to accept this while working with Magento2 projects. The possible options of getting SSH connections are written as below:

**1)** You can create public and private key in your hosting cpanel and can access SSH panel through Putty (SSH Client) software. You can download it from https://www.putty.org/. For detailed steps and information you may follow this link

> https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/ssh/shared-reseller-ssh/

**2)** If you are using Ubuntu/Linux system then you can try below command from console:

> ssh user@ipaddress

Here, you need to enter your cPanel user name and static private IP address of your cpanel. Once you press enter it will ask for password. You need to enter your cpanel password and you will be able to establish SSH connection.

**3)** The last and best option would be to get dedicated hosting server to get things working smoothly. This option will provide better and easy way to operate SSH connection.

I hope this help to you. If you have any further queries feel free to ask.

Happy to help!

Thanks,